# A property of a kind of product integral

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

Please, could you say to me which property was utilized here?

$$\int_0^\infty \int_0^x f(a)g(x-a)\,da\, dx=\int_0^\infty f(a)\,da\int_0^\infty g(x)\, dx$$

Many thanks!

Comment: You must be careful with Fubini, $\int_0^x ... dx$ does not make sense.

Comment: You're correct, I'll erase the attempt. Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\int_0^\infty \int_0^x f(a)g(x-a)\,da\, dx$=$\int_0^\infty \int_a^\infty f(a)g(x-a)\,dx\, da=\int_0^\infty f(a)\,da\int_0^\infty g(x)\, dx$

The first "=" is due to Fubini and $a\leq x$, you integrate both sides over the set $\{(a,x)\in \mathbb{R}^2 : 0\leq a\leq x\}$

Comment: Many thanks for this post.